# How to authenticate with mongoimport to a specific database using Docker and a bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, mongoimport

I am using a dockerfile and bash script

*It should be noted that the mongo db is already running and I can interactively connect to it so this is not an issue.*

Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo

WORKDIR /root
ENV PATH /root/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /root/bin

COPY import_files/latest.csv .
COPY import_files/field_file_types.txt .
COPY scripts/import.sh .

RUN chmod +x import.sh
CMD sh /root/bin/import.sh
```

import.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ENV_HOST="mongo1"
ENV_USER="user"
ENV_PASS="pass"
ENV_DB="mydb"
ENV_TABLE="mycollection"

# mongoimport -h "${ENV_HOST}:27017" -u "${ENV_USER}" -p "${ENV_PASS}" -c $ENV_TABLE --authenticationDatabase ${ENV_DB} --type csv --file ./latest.csv --columnsHaveTypes --fieldFile=./field_file_types.txt 

mongoimport  --uri "mongodb://${ENV_USER}:${ENV_PASS}@${ENV_HOST}/${ENV_DB}" -c $ENV_TABLE --type csv --file ./latest.csv --columnsHaveTypes --fieldFile=./field_file_types.txt 

exit 0
```

This is my mongo import statement

```
mongoimport 
-h "mongo1:27017" 
-u "user" 
-p "pass" 
-c "mycollection" 
--authenticationDatabase "mydb" 
--type csv 
--file ./latest.csv 
--columnsHaveTypes 
--fieldFile=./field_file_types.txt
```

Which in my console outputs like this:

```
mongodb://user:pass@mongo1:27017/admin mydb mycollection
```

And I get error:

> error parsing command line options: Invalid Options: Cannot specify different username in connection URI and command-line option ("user" was specified in the URI and "mycollection" was specified in the --username option)

I have also tried it as a uri:

```
mongoimport  --uri "mongodb://user:pass@mongo1/mydb" -c mycollection --type csv --file ./latest.csv --columnsHaveTypes --fieldFile=./field_file_types.txt
```

Which in my console looks like this:

```
Mongo import csv = mongodb://user:pass@mongo1:27017/admin mydb mycollection
Enter password:
```

Why is it asking for password? I provided it as above? Also its exactly the same output as the previous example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out when I was running docker-compose, I had a script which granted me permission to all databases: **(but only if I login as an admin)**

```
mongo <<EOF
use admin 
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "${MONGO_USER}",
    pwd: "${MONGO_PASS}",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)

use ${MONGO_DB}
db.createCollection("${MONGO_COLLECTION}")
EOF
```

This means when I connect to mongo I must connect via 'admin' in order to access the other databases. To access the database in question I can include it in the uri string but I must also add -

```
--authenticationDatabase admin
```

import script example:

```
mongoimport  --uri "mongodb://user:passt@mongo1/db" -c todos --type csv --file /data/db/latest.csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields "id.auto(),todoText.string(),created_timestamp.date(2006-01-02 15:04:05),completed.date(2006-01-02 15:04:05)" --authenticationDatabase admin
```